# JPGraph PieGraph SetMargin does not work

Tags: php, jpgraph

I'm trying to make a very simple Pie Graph with JPGraph but SetMargin does not work at all for PieGraph. I've even tried with the examples from JPGraph's site, and changing the margin in their examples doesn't do anything.

Here is the very simple example I'm working with

```
$graph = new PieGraph(300,400);
$p1 = new PiePlot(array(20,50,75,50));
$graph->Add($p1);
$graph->SetMargin(10,10,1,100);
$graph->Stroke();
```

Regardless of what I set the margins to, nothing changes. I've read that for Bar or Line charts you may need to disable the theme, but even adding

```
$graph->graph_theme = null;
```

Does nothing.

Anyone able to achieve this?

Answer (score 3):

I used the following:

```
$pieplot->SetSize(0.3);
```

Maybe, it doesn't work with 3d pie plots. 
I set the size in a regular pie plot and then I changed the type of graphic.

Also, you can change the center position:

```
$pieplot->SetCenter(0.5, 0.4);
```

Comment: Just a detail: `$pieplot->SetCenter(0.5, 0.4);` needs to be placed after calling `$graph->Add($pieplot)`